# How to check if user started following

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I've added linkedin follow button into my page.

```
<script type='IN/FollowCompany' data-id='66666' data-counter='top'></script>
```

It works good but I need to do something when user click on the follow button and started following the company. Is there an event which I can listen?

Comment: What does linked-in's doumentation on this feature say?

Comment: Official documentation is very weak, I cannot find out anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the IN/FollowCompany script does not support any such callback.  I will make note of your request and use case though for the future!

Answer (score -1):

Add the following attribute to the script tag:

```
      data-onclick="onClickFunction"
```

where onClickFunction is your function.

Comment: Was this just a guess, or based on knowledge of linked-in integration? If the latter, a link to some relevant information would help.

Comment: It was a hunch, I took help from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466789/linkedin-apply-button-callback-and-jquery-or-ext-callbacks-in-general, however, this question is for an Apply button, I guessed it might work similarly for a follow button.